# Unable to delete a stubborn file on OSX

Tags: macos

I am attempting to delete a file from the bin or trash on my mac OSX system to no avail. I have tried most things. The TrashIt app failed and I started looking into terminal commands to help.

I have read a number of articles suggesting various methods like

```
> rm -rf /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/Your_Short_Name/.Trash/Linotype \FontExplorer \X.app
```

or even

```
> sudo rm -rf
```

I tried moving it to the /tmp folder in the hope that it would go away as was also suggested. I may just leave it in there as one user has done on another post in this community.

I don't know if this app which appears to hold no data is still connecting to something on my machine which prevents its removal? I believe `lsof` might be a terminal program that would help here but I dont appear to have it. There are folders contained within when I go to `view package contents`

I get this error when attempting to remove it from the trash using
`sudo rm -f` .

```
.Trash sudo rm -rf Linotype\ FontExplorer\ X.app
rm: Linotype FontExplorer X.app/Contents/Resources/csf: Directory not empty
rm: Linotype FontExplorer X.app/Contents/Resources: Directory not empty
rm: Linotype FontExplorer X.app/Contents: Directory not empty
rm: Linotype FontExplorer X.app: Directory not empty
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unless you have first uninstalled all the plugins & moved your fonts, it's probably still active. You can't delete a running app. https://www.fontexplorerx.com/macfaq/ In general, any app that needed an installer rather than just drag to Applications will need an uninstaller or uninstall process.

Comment: What's in the directory that's the source of the problem, "Linotype FontExplorer X.app/Contents/Resources/csf"?  Try to "cd" into there and "rm -f" those files.  And restart the Mac in safe mode or whatever they call it, so apps like this won't start up.